# Improving Querying on View Table that is referencing a Base Table by adding indexing on columns in Base Table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a question. Would performance on querying a view table on MySQL running on Cloud SQL improve if I indexed the base table where a particular view table is using as a reference?

For context, there are two tables B and V, where V is the view table that is referencing data from the base table B. If I add indexing on some column x, and y, on B, would it help improve querying performance on V where I use x and y as filters?

Comment: Maybe.  We will need to see a specific Table & View & Index to give you a specific answer for that specific Table & View & Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick experiment can confirm this:

```
mysql> create table B (id serial primary key, x int, y int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> create view V as select * from B;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain select * from V where x = 123;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table B add key (x);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select * from V where x = 123;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ref  | x             | x    | 5       | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html says:

> Indexes can be used for views processed using the merge algorithm. However, a view that is processed with the temptable algorithm is unable to take advantage of indexes on its underlying tables (although indexes can be used during generation of the temporary tables).

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html for more details on view algorithms.